# Django Razorpay integration

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, razorpay

I want to integrate my website with razorpay, but I am lacking with the correct resource or tutorial for that. Actually I want a wallet in my website in which a user add money in his/her wallet by simply entering the amount in form and submitting the form. But I don't known how to link all files like models.py views.py urls.py and as well as the templates file. The attempt is given below please help!

```
class PaymentDtails(models.Model):
      paymentby=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete='CASCADE',null=True)
      razorpay_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      payment = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
      amount=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

forms.py

```
class AddMoneyForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
          model= PaymentDetails
          fields=('amount',)
```

please help me to integrate all that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Razorpay as your payment gateway, you can use the wallet service provided by Razorpay.
Razorpay provides closed wallet solutions, that you can use and make your implementation simpler.
get in touch with support team of Razorpay they will guide you on how to implement this.